# Why is Sublime Text not executing my program? Compiler issue?

Tags: c++, ide, sublimetext

**Sublime Text not executing code:** I have written a simple program in C++ that works perfectly fine in the Command Prompt and Visual Studio Code, yet fails to initiate any output when written in Sublime Text. The only output that it executes is, `[Finished in 438ms]` or something along those lines... Any help would be much appreciated. I have an image of the output and the source code listed below:
[(Sublime Text output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3i0l.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your sublime installation may not be configured properly for c++ compilation. You have to hook up the Sublime to a compiler on your machine.

There are many ways to do so depending on your setup, but here is an example of one method.
https://www.programmersought.com/article/50631946316/